# Protein ,Fat and carbs for vegetarian-obese

Tags: protein, fat, carbohydrate, vegetarian, obesity

I'm obese . Goal is to lose fat .

What are the sources of protein for vegetarian ?  I'm currently using Quorn product but range is limited .

How about Fat and Carbs , do both need to low ?

Comment: Macros are very important. I have seen ton of people lose fat thanks to following their macros.
It is a common beginner mistake, thinking, that fat and carbs are bad. You need both. Use some site to calculate your macros. Its usually 40/40/20 pro/carb/fat, but it depends highly on your activity level.
Being a vegeterian is a huge burden you have taken on yourself, what is the reason behind your choice?

Comment: I eat moderate level of Chicken and Duck but any read meat. I checked here http://macronutrientcalculator.com/ 45/25/30 According to that my target intake should be 1444 per day to reduce 1kg per week. I'm following a low carb diet as have family history of type 2 diabetics

Comment: But carbs are not the enemy...You need carbs, read about glycemic index. It will help you control your diabetes.
People who say that low carb diet is good, just do not know anything. Carb cycling, that is another story.
I would keep carbs and protein closer together.
Also...1444 per day? Are you insane, how much do you weight?
try this 
http://www.calculator.net/calorie-calculator.html

Comment: "You need 1,388 Calories/day to lose 1 kg per week." 98kg 184cm

Comment: You are not obese...
Instead of starting to lose fat, start with trying to gain some muscle, Have a calorie intake to maintain your weight. That is what is did at start. Replace fat with muscle. After that you can start shredding down.

Comment: What should I do to "Replace fat with muscle" ? I recently started to have http://www.onacademy.co.uk/lean-whey 26g as the first thing in the morning . Added more veggies/cheese/butter and cut down bread/rice

Comment: Carbs, are not your damn enemy man. Cut out sugars, that is the only bad carb source. Sugars from fruits are still good.
With your weight, i would take at least 200 g of protein a day and match carbs with it. Something like 200 carb and 50-80 g on fat. Make them match your macros more or likely, but with your weight 200 g of protein is a must.
That is a very expensive protein you are looking at.
My favorite of all time is ON 100% Gold standart. 
Dont believe in the fast absorption bogus. And you do not need some expensive lean whey. Less carbs from other sources will be cheaper. And lift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20791/discussion-between-nish1013-and-s3v3ns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to recap our discussion.
At your weight and height, you are not obese.
I would highly recommend exercising and following your macros, that can be calculated [here](http://calculator.net/calorie-calculator.html)

A very good site, to track your macros is [myfitnesspal](http://myfitnesspal.com)

If would also look into something called [intermittent fasting](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2013/08/06/a-beginners-guide-to-intermittent-fasting/)
But, since you said your family has a history of diabetes i would strongly recommend talking to your doctor about this before hand. I have followed this life style for over a year now, and i love it.

Also, it is very important to remember, that carbs are not the enemy, sugars are.
There are many different carb sources that are healthy, like oats and different greens.
Your body needs carbs for energy, without it, no energy, no muscles.

The rule of thumb is to consume at least 1 g of protein per 1 pound of body weight, this has worked for me, for thousand of others and it will work for you too.

Every other day you can do some cardio after your weight lifting workout, but take it easy in the start, see your limits, do not injure yourself and most important, have fun.

As for protein sources, try to get everything from whole foods, if you can't then turn to protein powders. They help, but they can't replace a good meal.
When buying protein, it is important to get as much protein per serving as possible and keeping sugars low. After a workout you have 24-48 hours(depending on your body) to consume your proteins, so don't listen to supplement companies about fast releasing or slow releasing proteins. An ordinary Whey protein will do the trick.

Veganism is a burden, and depending on how hardcore you are your sources of proteins will shiver. Egg whites are the best out there. 1 egg white = 4 g of protein. 
Chicken is also a very good source of protein.
As a vegan you could get your protein from nuts,beans,soy(However, since you are a man i do not recommend soy to you, as a matter of fact, i would stay as far as possible from it). and of course, the best bodybuilding meal out there : oatmeal.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about negative effect of Soya. More info for others too http://www.nhs.uk/news/2008/07July/Pages/Soyabasedfoodandmalefertility.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry too much about the macronutrients to begin with. Try to eat healthy and exercise, that will get you started. If you eat some milk products (yoghurt, cheese, milk) beans or nuts you'll get your share of protein.

Forming good eating and exercising habits is the key because otherwise it will remain a constant battle against your old habits!